# How can I assign an int variable to an int array int C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to realize math operations and write in the array, I send parameters as int, but error says invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript.

```
string clients[5][2];
string products[7];
string strPrices[7];
int prices[7];
int resumen[5][2];
```

```
void selectOption(int i, int opc, int cantidad){

    if(opc==1){
        clients[i][1] = ""+cantidad+products[0];
    } else if(opc==2){
        clients[i][1] = ""+cantidad+products[1];
    } else if(opc==3){
        clients[i][1] = ""+cantidad+products[2];
    } else if(opc==4){
        clients[i][1] = ""+cantidad+products[3];
    } else if(opc==5){
        clients[i][1] = ""+cantidad+products[4];
    } else if(opc==6){
        clients[i][1] = ""+cantidad+products[5];
    } else{
        clients[i][1] = ""+cantidad+products[6];
    }

    prices[i][0] = i+1; //--- error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
    prices[i][1] = prices[i]*cantidad; //--- error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
}
```

Comment: For your arrays use : std::vector<int>, for strings use std::string and to convert strings to integers use std::stoi (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: You have to decide is `prices` a 1D array or a 2D array? Because at the moment half of your code says it's a 1D array and the other half says it's a 2D array. First decide what you really want it to be, then fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted above, I suppose that `prices` is an int array, and subscribing an int array will get an int, which means `prices[i]` is a legal expression and its type is int. However, int is not subscribable, which means `prices[i][0]` is not a legal expression, so the compiler is reporting an error.